# RTC post-build deliver option with Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event, rtc

Is it possible to execute a **Post-build Deliver** when using Jenkins server with RTC source?

This is my process;

1. When a job is started Jenkins connects to RTC Source using the Rational Team Concert plugin and fetches the required code. (Connects to RTC using a build definition which contains details of the workspace to use. This build definition also contains details of the post-build steps)
2. Jenkins tests/builds/deploys application
3. Job completes with a status of success.

When I open the results view for the build definition associated with this Jenkins job i notice the absence of any post-build delivery information in the **Contribution Summary**.

Using the setup I've mentioned should Post-build Delivery be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@niloc,

The ability to initiate a post-deliver option currently only exists in JBE (Jazz Build Engine).  There currently is an enhancement open to improve this for the [Team Concert Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Concert+Plugin) for Hudson/Jenkins ... [Teamconcert plugin to trigger Post-Build Events configured in RTC Build Definition](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18421).

However, Heather describes a work around in a comment on 05/Dec/13.

Scott

Comment: Hm... I configured a jazz build engine, run the jbe magic command, finds no errors in any log other than that the build step is running, but nothing happens. Where do I look for errors?

Answer (score 1):

The post-build delivery step can only be set in the build definition with in RTC.

Jenkins won't know anything about it: it doesn't execute that step. RTC does.

Comment: thanks @VonC so i just want to clarify; Jenkins will use the build definition to pull down the repository workspace however the post-build step will not be executed because Jenkins doesn't know or care that it exists. However when Jenkins completes it does send a status back to the RTC build definition and RTC in turn marks the build definition run as a success. So there is cross communication between Jenkins and RTC.

Comment: @niloc Jenkins calls RTC, and then waits for RTC to give the sources. RTC starts by putting a snapshot (as it does for any build, Jenkins or not), then gives the sources. When RTC is notified by Jenkins of the job completion, it should trigger the post-build deliver step. Jenkins isn't aware of that final step.